# How can I calculate the coordinates of segments that form a hanging chain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

I'm trying to get a chain physics model with segments. 
I'm feeling rather stupid, but how can I calculate which is the new position of each dot when the chain moves its ends?

[image]

expressed in another way and considering just three segments of the same length: which is the way for automatically calculating the different P1, P2. when an end moves?

[image]

Comment: Create a free body diagram for each segment? This should give you a set of simultaneous equations for the $x$ and $y$ components of the forces acting on each dot.

Comment: You may find my answer here helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/421965/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring I did see it, however i cannot understand how to get the equilibrium in the formulas of your answer. But that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to explain it better than what I said in that answer. But if you'd like to know how to calculate the points on a chain given its length and the coordinates of its end points see the comments at the start of my old POV-Ray code [here](http://news.povray.org/povray.binaries.images/thread/%3Cweb.42edf3bf208413009143b5c90%40news.povray.org%3E/) Also see [here](http://news.povray.org/povray.binaries.scene-files/message/%3Cweb.4318272930c60c8bbc2b06b10%40news.povray.org%3E/#%3Cweb.4318272930c60c8bbc2b06b10%40news.povray.org%3E).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @PM2Ring. What I cannot understand is how you fix the two ends. In your drawing, P0 is the lowest point, and the rest of coordinates come from it, isnt?

Comment: That's right. Working from the lowest point makes things relatively easy. If you don't know the lowest point, but you know the coords of the end points & the length of the chain then you can use the technique that my POV-Ray code uses. There's also good info on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary

Comment: @PM2Ring is your model suitable for ropes hanging freely from one point?

Comment: No, it assumes there are 2 fixed endpoints. A rope hanging freely from 1 point should just hang in a vertical line.

Answer (score 1):

If your chain has more than just a few links, it can be modeled with a catenary curve.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary . Scroll down for derivations.)  In the formula,  y = a cosh(x/a),  x= 0 at the bottom of the loop, and y = a at x=0.   Calculate a = (s^2 – h^2)/(2h)  where, s, is half the length of your chain, and, h, is the vertical distance from the bottom of the loop to the point of support.  For any other, s, along the arc from the bottom, x = a arcsinh(s/a) .

Comment: Yes, that's the case for two hanging points. But my project was just for one

Comment: If there is only one point of support, the chain will hang straight down.

Comment: Yes, but that's the quasistatic state. If I drive the rope, I would like to see the dynamics.

Comment: How do you plan to drive the rope?

Comment: I've started to model it like a single pendulum for a start. The pivot is moved in a horizontal movement with a sudden stop.